# What happens to the Idols in Temples at end of Kalpa as Rudra destroys Bhuloka at end of Kalpa?

Tags: temple, kali-yuga, shakti, sati-goddess

Please don't get offended and i'm just curious. According to Skanda Purana, Goddess Sati self immolated in [Swayamabhuva Manvanatara of Pitri Kalpa](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/27477/62f_chapter_19_1.pdf). She was born again as Parvathi Devi at [beginning of current Vaishvara Manvantara of Swetha Varaha Kalpa](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/27478/62f_chapter_19_2.pdf). When Lord Rudra was carrying her body, Lord Narayana used His Sudarshana Chakra which cut Her body into different parts and these organs had fallen in different locations on Earth and these places are called as [Shakti Peeths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakti_Peetha).

But at the end of Kalpa, Rudra destroys Earth. But i'm not sure about transition times of Pitri Kalpa and Swetha Varaha Kalpa, as Lord Vishnu's Avatar Varaha rescued Earth from demon Hiranyaksha who hid Earth in waters. So, i think Earth was not destroyed by Rudra at end of Pitri Kalpa. Still people worship the Shakti Peets of Previous Kalpa where Goddess organs are well preserved and worshipped with high veneration. So, my questions are

- Was Earth destroyed at end of previous Kalpa? If Yes, how Goddess organs were preserved during Pralaya?
- Generally, what happens to Idols in various temples at the end of Kalpa? I think temples are built only in Kali Yuga. Is this true?
- There's a [legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manikarnika_Ghat#Significance) for Holy City of Kashi where it will be not be destroyed even at at end of Kalpa. So, is there any story for these Shaktipeets in particular and other temples in general?

Comment: Yeah, temples for the most part are built in the Kali Yuga; in other Yugas other forms of worship are more common.  A Pralaya would certainly destroy man-made statues, but I'm not sure what happens to Swayambhu statues.

Comment: You know I am not entirely sure of the Pitri Kalpa being the **Kalpa** when Sati immolated herself because that places a huge amount of time and several things which are said to have occurred in Varaha Kalpa cannot occur otherwise.

Comment: @Surya Yeah. This contradicts some events. But I think all Swayambhuva Temples and some places such as Prayag, Kasi are not destroyed at end of Kalpa (mentioned in Skanda Purana). I need to check references for Shakti Peeths.

Comment: I went through the Skanda Purana excerpt. Though it implies that Daksha's was formerly born in Pitri Kalpa it doesn't say that Sati immolated herself in pitri Kalpa.

Comment: @Surya " In this Väraha Kalpa, you became Pärvati 
obtained by Himavän through his penance, when the Cäksusa 
Manvantara has passed off. Due to the anger of Dak'a you had  to be separated from me for the duration Of a day Of Brahma.Your span of life is the period of his six months. The sages Who were formerly cursed by me Out Of my anger in your Case, are also born along With you in the Vaivasvata Manvantara. Formerly, in the Sväyambhuva Manvantara they had been cursed at the time of the Yagfia of Dakya. O goddess, they are reborn in this Kalpa after the Cäksusa Manvantara has elapsed".

Comment: @Surya Daksha Yagna happened in Svayambhuva Manvantara of Pitri Kalpa. But they were separated for duration of day of Brahma, as said by Siva. But if Yagna happened in Swayambhuva and if she cast her body during Yagna, she would be separated by 21 Manvantaras which is more than 1 Kalpa (one day of Brahma).

Comment: But if you see, if Sati was really separated for 21 Manvantaras, then Samudra Mathana couldn't have happened, unless this gives weightage to Keshav's question that it happened twice.

Comment: But there is also the thing that most of the Parvati/Sati incidents happen in Vaivasvata only, and nothing much happens in the first six Manvantaras.

Comment: @Surya Only two things could be logical now. One, Kalpa bedha and another, Sagara Madhanam should happen twice. But i feel, as marriage of Rudra (one of thrimurtis and creation gets completed only after Rudra marries Sati and Brahma worked hard  to make this possible as creation is his job) is an important event, it must happen the same way with no changes in various Kalpas. Even crow, which saw past, says the same. With this logic, we should believe what majority of Puranas say on this and at the same time we can't neglect Skanda Purana which is a Shaiva Purana.