# What happens to deities at the end of their life cycle?

Tags: gods

What happens to different deities we worship at the end of their life cycle. Will they merge back into Parabrahma?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is moksha guaranteed for everyone?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/is-moksha-guaranteed-for-everyone) ... At the end of the cycle everything merges back to the Brahman (viz. Moksha), including the deities. Remember that "deities" are also beings, just at the higher plane of existence.

Comment: Related: [What happens to the Idols in Temples at end of Kalpa as Rudra destroys Bhuloka at end of Kalpa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11239/1049)

Comment: they are reborn in this world...

Comment: @Swami I don't get you

Comment: the devis and devas are positions that are filled by jivas who desired to those positions and have done the necessary sacrifices and austerities in a prior cycle to attain to that position. Once their karma that got them to the position of a devi has run its course, they are reborn again in this world.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I was more asking about the deities we worship in temples of Lord muruga, Lord Rudra, Lord Vishnu of this universe, Lord Parvati, Lord Mahalaxmi etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Vishnu Puran: Part 1: Chapter 15](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp050.htm),

> There were twelve celebrated deities in a former Manwantara, called **Tushitas**, who, upon the approach of the present period, or in the reign of the last Manu, Chákshusha, assembled, and said to one another,

> "Come, let us quickly enter into the womb of Adití, that we may be born in the next Manwantara, for thereby we shall again enjoy the rank of gods:"

> and accordingly they were born the sons of Kaśyapa, the son of Maríchi, by Adití, the daughter of Daksha; thence named the **twelve Ádityas**; whose appellations were respectively, Vishńu, Śakra, Áryaman, Dhútí, Twásht́ri, Púshan, Vivaswat, Savitri, Mitra, Varuńa, Anśa, and Bhaga.

> These, who in the Chákshusha Manwantara were the gods called Tushitas, were called the twelve Ádityas in the Manwantara of Vaivaśwata.

Below are the Sanskrit verses and Hindi translation:

> [image]
> [image]

But, it's not always the case. As mentioned in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22680/what-will-happen-to-hanuman-and-the-other-chiranjivis-after-the-end-of-the-kali/22693#22693), in 8th Manwantara, the Indra will be Bali, the sinless son of Virochana instead of current Indra (Śakra or Purandara).

So sometimes, deities take rebirth and again attain the post of deities and sometime they don't attain the same post.

Finally, they merge back into Brahman (Maha Vishnu as per Vaishnavism), for Manu it is mentioned in **PADMA PURANA: SECTION I: SRSTIKHANDA: Chapter 7 Description of Manu Periods**:

> 113. Past and future Manus are (thus) described (by
>      me). O prince, a thousandyugas will be occupied by (each
>      one of) these.

> 114. Having created all these mobile and immobile beings
>      in their own periods, they will, at the end of the kalpa, obtain
>      release along with Brahma.

> 115. At the end of a thousand yugas they will again and
>      again perish, and led by Brahma will then be absorbed in
>      Visnu.

---

Related

[What is the Life span of Hindu gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23190/what-is-the-life-span-of-hindu-gods/23603#23603)