# Adityas and Kashyapa before the 7th manvantara

Tags: puranas, gods, adityas

It is believed that Kashyapa gave birth to Adityas, with his wife Aditi, who went on to become Devtas in the present manvatara which is the 7th.

Where was Rishi Kashyap in the first 6 manvataras and which events was he involved in if he only gave birth to Adityas in the 7th manvatara?

Or did Adityas have any existence before this manvatara before becoming the Devtas?

Please mention the source along with your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to deities at the end of their life cycle?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28741/what-happens-to-deities-at-the-end-of-their-life-cycle)

Comment: "Or did Adityas have any existence before this manvatara before becoming the Devtas?" -- yes, "These, who in the Chákshusha Manwantara were the gods called Tushitas, were called the twelve Ádityas in the Manwantara of Vaivaśwata."...this is answered in above Q "What happens to deities at the end of their life cycle? "...

Answer (score 1):

Kaśyapa was least there by the second Manvantara, according to [the Vishnu Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115957.html).

> (Probably Parāśara said:)
>
> ...
>
> These were the children of Kaśyapa, whether movable or stationary, whose descendants multiplied infinitely through successive generations[22]. This creation, oh Brahman, took place in the second or Svārociṣa Manvantara.

Comment: Can you please mention the source of this as well